# Having problems with averaging unspecified range of columns

Tags: excel, vba, average

I'm working on trying to average all the rows in a column over multiple columns (an uncertain amount of them). I know I can write a code to do each column one at a time but I was hoping to find a way to shorten the code length.

So far, I've managed to average one column (B), but seem unable to do an auto-fill to the last column, which can change in length. I've also tried to do an if-statement like "if there is a value in above row then do average", but I'm not very good at using VBA so don't really know how to do it.
I need help doing the same averaging as seen in the code below over all the columns which contain values in them. My values specifically start in row 5 and go down to an unspecified range.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim myavg As Range

Set rng1 = Range("B5")
Set rng2 = Range("B5").End(xlDown)
Set myavg = Range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

myavg = "=Average(" & rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address & ")"
```

Comment: Small note:  It is generally recommended to start at the bottom and use `End(xlUp)` instead of starting at the top and using `End(xlDown)` - if the bottommost cell of data is B5, then this will go all the way down to B1048576.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did try that and ended up averaging all the data from the last cell on my row all the way down thousands of rows because I'm very bad at writing VBAs. Thus, I gave up and wrote it this way instead.

Comment: Try `Set rng2 = Range("B5").EntireColumn.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)` - this will start at the bottom of the column, and move up until it hits either Data, or the top of the Worksheet.  Then you can use `Set myavg = rng2.Offset(1,0)` to get the next cell down

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Do you also know how I could easily do that same formula over the next couple of columns? Right now I wish to average the rows in all columns until I get to S (but as mentioned above, this column range might change).

Comment: @Jesse you can use `Do While rng1.Value <> ""` and in each loop offset `rng1` by one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Do While` as follows:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim myavg As Range

Set rng1 = Range("B5")

Do While rng1.Value <> ""
    Set rng2 = Cells(Rows.count, rng1.Column).End(xlUp) ' using @Chronocidal's suggestion above
    Set myavg = rng2.Offset(1, 0)

    myavg.Formula = "=Average(" & rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address & ")"

    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
Loop
```

Comment: You guys are awesome. That worked wonderfully! Thank you so much.